# How to add entire folder of wallpapers in KDE plasma 5

Tags: 18.04, kde, desktop-background, plasma-5

When changing the wallpaper in KDE plasma 5 (on 18.04 if that matters) there's a button that says "+ Add Image...". Which is cool if you want to add *a* wallpaper, but I have *hundreds* in a folder in Dropbox to sync to all my devices.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add an entire folder (short of symlinking it to the default wallpaper folder), as is possible to do in pretty much every other DE either by selecting the folder or highlight-select a bunch and then open.

My duckduckgo and google searches for "bulk add wallpaper" and "add wallpaper folder" turned up nothing.

Comment: Is [How to Bulk Add Wallpaper Folder in KDE Plasma 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tC0oHuiGB0) of any use? If it's not what you want, submitting a "feature request" [here](https://bugs.kde.org) may help.

Comment: @DKBose that is helpful, did not know about the drag-n-drop. But yeah, very different than what I'm used to with, well, everything not KDE. And I mentioned symlinking in my question, I just find that to be... not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised there isn't a proper answer for this question yet (even if it can be pieced together through the comments what you need to do).

1. Open the KDE desktop settings
2. Open your wallpaper folder
3. Select all the images you wanna add
4. Drag & drop the images to the KDE desktop settings wallpaper section.

Bonus: The default KDE wallpaper directory is in **/usr/share/wallpapers/**

If you would like to remove them run:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/wallpapers/*
```

**Warning**: SDDM (login screen) themes also tend to use images from this folder as their default backgrounds, if your login screen turns white after deleting all the default wallpapers, you can fix it by setting a custom wallpaper for your SDDM theme.

Answer (score 0):

Dude just find the wallpaper folder in your filesystem and add the images into it might have to do some digging around in the filesystem to find the folder, but you can also open the file manager as sudo then copy your images from the wallpaper folder you have to the default wallpaper folder of KDE.

Comment: I mention symlinking to the default wallpaper folder in the question, and I'll repeat why I don't want to do it: I shouldn't have to. Why should a user have to *root around in the system directories* to do something as simple as adding some wallpapers?